# Stability order of p-quinone, o-quinone and diphenoquinone

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability

#### Question

> Determine stability order:
>
> [image: 1: 1,4-benzoquinone; 2: 1,2-benzoquinone; 3: 4,4'-diphenoquinone]

#### Answer

> **1** > **2** > **3**

#### Thoughts

I found this question quite tricky and confusing. According to my concepts and logic

- **3** should be non-aromatic, while **1** and **2** are antiaromatic.
- Also there is a lone pair repulsion in **2**.

After racking my brain I up came with the answer of **3** > **1** > **2** (arguably most convincing for me), which is wrong according to the actually given answer.

So, while my answer for **1** > **2** is correct, I still have no explanation for **3**.

Kindly help me on what I am missing or if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: I guess answer given is wrong, because II (ortho-quinone) is highly unstable, at least less stable than I (para-quinone)...

Comment: @Zenix the ans given says 1>2>3. Yeah and agreed that 2 is less stable than 1 but what about the 3rd one?.I am confused about 1and 3 and their relative order along with an explanation.

Comment: "Benzoquinone is not anti-aromatic, it is not a simple cyclic array of 4 pi electrons. In fact, anti-aromatic compounds distort to some other geometry so they are no longer anti-aromatic, hence more stable." - @ron

Comment: @Zenix ohk so I wasn't aware of that...but will u add something about 3???

Comment: I currently don't know anything more. I will try to answer it after revising quinones. Not sure, if will be able to..